# javascript running locally but not on apache

Tags: javascript, apache

I'm using [JSValidate](http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=903&c=5807535) to validate a form, the form gets validated correctly when I access it via `File-> Open File`, but not when I type `localhost/formname` on my address bar.

When ran from `localhost/formname` the form behaves as if the Javascript weren't there. This doesn't happen in my apache server at home, yet it does happen at work. What could it be?

*both machines run ubuntu's firefox, with javascript enabled.

[Full code](http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=903&c=5807535)

Comment: There is no way to help here without a code sample.

Comment: Are all the JavaScripts properly referenced? Generally have absolute paths. I see in your code sample that they were relative.

Comment: yeah, it must be a reference issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/), [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) and possibly [Console²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1815/).
That are Firefox add-ons which can aid you in debugging.

Take a look in your Error Console, search for errors.
Do you have the "scriptaculous" folder in the same folder?

Comment: yeah, scriptaculous is in the same folder.

Comment: Have you checked your Error Console?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't show a thing. I'm gonna copy my entire www folder and put it on my office's apache, it's empty anyway.

Comment: Heh, it does show an error, but when fixed doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: A misplaced instantiation of an old form checker that I ended up erasing. 

Validator is not defined
file:///home/softrain/Escritorio/1%20PROYECTO/formconvalidate5.html
Line 662